# Flutter I cant get address from geolocator

Tags: flutter, dart

i can get location but i want to get address from this
location .
i use **geolocator** plugin and this is my _getAddress method :

```
 _getAddress() async {
   try {
      List<Placemark> placeMark = await 
      locator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition.longitude, 
      _currentPosition.longitude);
      Placemark place = placeMark[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
         "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, 
         ${place.country}";
       });

   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
}
```

}

how can i do that ?

and i have all location permissions .

this is my error from catch :

PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_COORDINATES, grpc
failed, null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`placemarkFromCoordinates` is no longer in the geolocator lib :

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

[image]

Comment: and i have to use geocoding ??

Comment: Yes it works the same way you did : https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding